# wlan0 miss after sudo apt upgrade

Tags: wireless, kernel

After sudo apt upgrade : kernel version 5.4.0.1052-raspi upgraded to 5.4.0.1095-raspi but suddently miss wlan0.
So the modules and linux-headers are checked and wifi interfaces used in 1052 is rtl8821cu and it is not found in 1095 kernel version. The new module found,rtl8192cu is loaded but still not found wlan0.

Please kindly suggest is there any complexity with new version of kernel.
It is in ubuntu20.04 of raspberry pi4.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2bc5:0401 Orbbec(R) ORBBEC Depth Sensor
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 040b:2000 Weltrend Semiconductor wired Keyboard [Dynex DX-WRK1401]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
hnet0     no wireless extensions.
eth1      no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

`lsmod |grep cfg` shows nothing.
cfg8821 is missing in new kernel.
`ls /lib/modules/5.4.0-1095-raspi/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`:

```
ath       intel              marvell   ray_cs.ko      rsi  virt_wifi.ko
atmel     intersil           mediatek  realtek        st   wl3501_cs.ko
broadcom  mac80211_hwsim.ko  ralink    rndis_wlan.ko  ti   zydas
```

`ls /lib/modules/5.4.0-1052-raspi/kernel/drivers/net/wireless`:

```
8821cu.ko  intel              mediatek   rndis_wlan.ko  virt_wifi.ko
ath        intersil           ralink     rsi            wl3501_cs.ko
atmel      mac80211_hwsim.ko  ray_cs.ko  st             zydas
broadcom   marvell            realtek    ti
```

`sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries Device 2711 (rev 20)
01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; iwconfig; lsmod |grep cfg`

Comment: Sometimes, wifi cards are on PCI stacks not USB.  Show the output of `sudo lspci`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand why wireless interface module is missed in upgraded version, the required module is installed again from this [rtl8821cu](https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU)and get back.